# Azure Analysis Services - Incremental Refresh

Tags: sql-server, azure, ssas

I'm struggling with a situation and some help would be appreciated. I have a Fact table with 250 million rows and it starts with data since 2016... Sometimes an old row, like from 2017, is update and I need to keep my Tabular model refreshed as well, but I can not refresh my entire model every single day. I used to do it easily on Qlikview merging the data from my database source with the rows that I already have in my model. Is there a way to query my rows from my tabular model e remove them if they are present in my recently updated rows query.

Answer (score 1):

You would use [Partitions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/analysis-services/tabular-models/partitions-ssas-tabular?view=sql-analysis-services-2019) for this.  You configure your table with separate queries for each partition, and then you can refresh the latest partition daily, and an older partition in case a change is made to older data.